# UIScrollview imbeded within UIPageviewController resizes after page turned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

So I have a UIPageviewController used that contains various news articles. The articles are presented on UIWebviews of varying lengths, and each UIWebview is contained within a UIScrollview. When the first article is loaded, everything works, and the user is able to scroll up and down the page and read the entire article. However, when the user swipes to the left or right to view the next article, the UIScrollview on that page is resized to only be the height of the screen and thus will only scroll enought to bounce back. I can tell that the UIWebview is longer than what is being shown because I have printed it's height, and when scrolling, you can see that the article continues. Also, when you swipe back to the initial article View, this UIScrollview is also resized to only be the screen size.

The UIWebView has it's content's loaded in the ArticleViewController's init method, and then is sized within the webViewDidLoad method like this:

```
CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
aWebView.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
aWebView.frame = frame;
```

This seems to work, although tell me if you think I should change it.

To get to each article, you click on it from a UITableview presenting each of the articles. Within the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath method for this, I set up the UIPageViewController like so:

```
UIPageViewController *articlesPageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
articlesPageViewController.dataSource = self;
articlesPageViewController.delegate = self;
```

**NVM! The Solution was turning off auto layout for the UIScrollview! Thanks everyone!**

Comment: Post your code. It seems like your UIWebView / UIScrollView resets every time you navigate to different pages in UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView { 
     CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
     frame.size.height = 1; 
     aWebView.frame = frame; 
     CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
     frame.size = fittingSize; 
     aWebView.frame = frame; NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height); 
}
```

Get height of the webview then set the content size of the scrollview

OR try this way:

```
CGFloat height = [[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
CGFloat width = [[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue]; 
CGRect frame = myWebView.frame; 
frame.size.height = height + 125.0; 
frame.size.width = width; 
myWebView.frame = frame; 
mainScrollView.contentSize = myWebView.bounds.size;
```

Comment: self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth, scrollViewHeight)];

Comment: Probably you will have scrollViewHeight reset , scroll contains Webview sometimes adjusts to the height of webview, To do that you can try logging the height of the webview that gets loaded and the scrollViewHeight

Comment: Ok, so I figured out, that what I'm doing is setting the scrollview's frame.size.height. This works for the first view controller for some reason. However, the scroll view's contentsize.height is always 0, no matter if it's the initial page or a subsequent page. Does this mean anything?

Comment: `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
}` Get height of the webview then set the content size of the scrollview

Comment: OR try this way:   CGFloat height = [[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
CGFloat width = [[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
CGRect frame = myWebView.frame;
frame.size.height = height + 125.0;
frame.size.width = width;
myWebView.frame = frame;
mainScrollView.contentSize = myWebView.bounds.size;

Comment: Thanks, I solved it though! The solution was turning off autolayout within Interface Builder. The Scrollview was resetting to be the size determined by autolayout

Comment: @MohamedJahaberSadiq I edited your answer with your comments. This is the preferred way to post answers. Your original question was flagged as low quality as it was. I did my best on the formatting but please verify it looks correct. This way you can also get credit for answering the question.